# Route Subdomain to Asp.net Core 2.1 Area

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, subdomain, multi-tenant, asp.net-mvc-areas

We cannot use SaasKit

We have an asp.net core 2.1 app. We would like to have it route incoming subdomains to specific areas so each tenant can have it's own _layout, views, controllers, etc.

```
website1.mydomain.com routes to Website1 Area

website2.mydomain.com routes to Website2 Area
```

Ideally it would have a clean url which does not include the area name.  In other words

We would not want to end up seeing...

```
website1.mydomain.com/Website1/Home/Index

website2.mydomain.com/Website2/Home/Index
```

But instead, we would like to have...

```
website1.mydomain.com/Home/Index

website2.mydomain.com/Home/Index
```

-

```
MyApplication 
  Areas 
     Website1 
        - Controllers 
            - HomeController 
                - Returns Index View 
        - Models 
        - Views 
            - Home 
                - Index 

     Website2 
        - Controllers 
            - HomeController 
                - Returns Index View 
        - Models 
        - Views 
            - Home 
                - Index
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason you can't use SaasKit?

Comment: I believe you can do this at IIS level. Look up IIS Virtual Directory